# .htaccess - if the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index.php but send 404 instead of 200

Tags: htaccess, 404

I have a catchall *.htaccess* directive like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Anything that doesn't exist and the URL is rewritten back to the index page. This is fine, however I want the header to be sent a 404 instead of a 200. How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the only way to do so is using `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

because with `RewriteRule` you are "masking" the error serving another page to the request.

Yet you must know that `ErrorDocument 404` won't change the URL of the page, thus you will have your homepage on a wrong URL.

Comment: I had to use `/index.php` instead of `index.php` but that worked. That makes more sense now. Thanks

Comment: @Jakobud If it worked mark the question as answered ...

Comment: "you will have your homepage on a wrong URL" - which is, incidentally, what the code in the question would do as well (internal rewrite).

Answer (score 1):

Your original rewrite rule will work.    You just need to modify `index.php` to return a 404.  You just need to include this line at the top

```
 header("Status: 404 Not Found");
```

At that point, your PHP script will be responsible for writing the content of the error page.  You will have implemented a custom 404.

Comment: Although you'd probably want to do this conditionally in the case of `index.php`. (Which you could easily do based on the URL.)

Answer (score 0):

A 404 is a dead-end, so you can not send a 404 *and* redirect unless you use a piece of JS on a 404 page, but I hate those "you will be redirected shortly..." pages.

My solution does not do *exactly* what you ask but you could do a lot more in the `404.php` file.

**Solution:**

in *.htaccess*:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

in `404.php`:

```
<?php
// Redirect and send 301 header (a redirect defaults to a 302)
header('Location: http://www.example.com/', TRUE, 301);
```

Comment: Not sure of the reasoning behind your "solution"? The 404 would seem to be completely superfluous in your example. As you state in your first line "you can not send a 404 _and_ redirect" - you seem to have demonstrated this in your example?

Comment: Although the server is handling the 404 as a 404 in my solution, the browser is sent a 301 header as a result of the PHP `header()` function. The reason for using `ErrorDocument 404` rather than a rewrite in my case was to do stuff in the 404.php file based on the request, I may want to redirect in some cases, and in other cases I may want to display a 404 page (which would have the 404 header).